# Certificate security with WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, security, ssl-certificate

I have a self-hosted WCF service using the WSHttpBinding that I'm trying to integrate certificate security.  I've found a lot of information through google to implement this, which I've followed.  Unfortunately, I get a 403 forbidden error when I try to access the service from my client and IE.

Below are the steps I took to get where I'm at.

I first ran this at the command prompt to create a certification authority:

```
makecert -sv SignRoot.pvk -cy authority -r signroot.cer -a sha1 -n "CN=Certification Authority" -ss my -sr localmachine
```

I then copied this new certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store on the local machine.

Next, I created a new certificate using the certification authority:

```
makecert -iv SignRoot.pvk -ic signroot.cer -cy end -pe -n CN="X.X.X.X" -ss my -sr    localmachine -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12
```

I copied this certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities and Personal stores for the current user.
Next, I grabbed the thumbprint of this certificate and the app id of my service and configured the port with this SSL certificate:

```
netsh http add sslcert hostnameport=0.0.0.0:50016 certhash=certificate_hash appid={app_guid}
```

I setup the WCF service like this:

```
Type hostType = Type.GetType(configurationElement.HostTypeDeclaration);
Type contractType = Type.GetType(configurationElement.ContractTypeDeclaration);

Uri baseAddress = new Uri(string.Format("https://{0}/", configurationElement.ServiceAddressPort));

ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(hostType, baseAddress);

WSHttpBinding wsHttpBinding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport, false);
wsHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

host.AddServiceEndpoint(contractType, wsHttpBinding,
            string.Format("{0}{1}", baseAddress, configurationElement.EndpointName));

host.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "X.X.X.X");

host.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "X.X.X.X");

host.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;

host.Open();
```

From the client side, I'm calling the service like this:

```
using (WcfServiceClient<IWcfService> serviceClient = WcfServiceClient<IWcfService>.Create())
{
    serviceClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
                            StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
                            StoreName.My,
                            X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
                            "X.X.X.X");                        

    bool = serviceClient.Instance.SomeMethod(string.Empty);
}
```

The server and client are both running on the same machine for now, but this service will be called from other machines in the end.  The server is running Windows Server 2012.  If I change the HttpClientCredentialType to None, everything works fine.  With it set to None, I also tried connecting from another machine and it failed, which is correct, because of the missing certificate.  I installed the certificate on that machine, and it worked.  I don't understand why I get error 403 forbidden using credential type = Certificate though.